# What will happen if I have 3,000 warnings but I chose to ignore them

Tags: java, warnings

I have to tune a Java EE application which **needs to handle a transaction over 40 tps.**

In each of every class, I see a lot of warnings such as unused variables, References to generic type Iterator should be parameterized, import ... is never used, local variable is never read and so on.

**Will all of these warnings cause any performance defect to the application?**

**Does Java smart enough not to create a variable that is never used in run-time?**

*I ran some tests on it and seems to be a memory hogging application; 10GB of heap can be filled up in less than 5 minutes with 1/4 of the throughput.

Comment: If you ignore 3000 warnings, then innocent ponies will die every time you run your program. More seriously, how can you expect us to answer that question? It all depends on the warning. Some could be benign, but some could indicate bugs in your code. Only you can tell which it is since only you can see the code. But 3000?! Time to tidy house.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Zalgo is the pony.

Comment: The same as with 2,999 warnings, though it becomes 1/2999-th more serious.

Comment: I think this explains what will happen. http://xkcd.com/292/

Comment: Whenever I see excessive warnings, I have found that the bulk of them can be attributed to generated code and things like implementing interfaces that pass parameters that you do not use or not providing ignore annotations on usage of raw types (inevitable when using older libraries).

Answer (score 3):

Nothing will not happen. You will continue working on dirty and hard-to-understand code. It may be dangerous: because if you do not use variable you probably wanted to use it but by mistake used other one, so probably you code is buggy and this bug will be found on Friday, 6PM when you are going to go to the cinema with the girl of your life... :(.

Fixing of 3000 warnings is doable task. I did it at least twice with big and dirty projects. it may take about day or two. If I were you I'd do this.

Answer (score 2):

It depends entirely on what the warnings are, and the surrounding code.

A warning such as "unchecked generic cast" is obviously fine, as it's the compiler telling you that it can't guarantee the type safety of the generics - this will end up generating the exact same bytecode as a "good" case though.  Ditto things like "unnecessary unboxing" where the compiler will insert the same call for you.

On the other hand, warnings such as "local variable is never read" could end up reflecting a potential slowdown.  Hotspot is pretty amazing at what it optimises, but there are limits to what it can assume.  This particular warning also implies that you are *populating* the local variable, and in general this can't be optimised away for a non-trivial case as it could have side effects.  In the absence of side effects, though, the calculation is a waste of cycles as it'll never be read.

But really, why ignore the warnings anyway?  They're there for a reason, and there's no excuse to e.g. use an unparameterised `Iterator` anyway.  (When the type of the underlying collection changes, you want the code not to compile until you change the iterator-reading code too.)

On the odd occasions where you can't avoid a warning but you're sure that it's fine (this is often the case with casting to a generic type), then use the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation to handle this.  Not only does it cause the compiler to shut up, but it also serves as a flag to other developers that "yes this looks a bit dodgy, but it's actually already because..." (and there should almost invariably be a comment explaining why).

When encountered with a warning, you should **fix it** and in extreme cases flag it as a false positive.  Ideally the compiler should always be returning zero warnings.

Answer (score 1):

I would ignore the performance issue. There is another good reason not to ignore the warnings.

If a compiler is giving you that many warnings, and you don't clean them up, it means that when there are legitimate problems with your code you will not notice because they will be buried in the snow of spurious error messages. A good software engineer tries to get their code to compile without error if only so that they can notice when there is a legitimate problem to be fixed.

Given the sheer number of errors here, I suspect you probably do have actual bugs in the code being concealed by the ocean of errors, and you should fix them.

Answer (score 1):

It's very unlikely that the problems indicated in those warnings (at least those you mention) have any direct impact on performance. Instead, they indicate low maintainability and bad developer practices. The warnings and the bad performance are both symptoms of the same underlying cause: incompetent developers.

Fixing those warnings will not make the code perform better, but it will make it more maintainable, so it will be easier to fix the performance problems.

Answer (score 0):

Most warnings are references to compile time issues, things that wouldn't affect performance IF they aren't causing defects, like you said.  The java compiler might be *probably* smart enough to optimize out primitives that aren't used, but all bets are off if those are classes.

Answer (score 0):

If your program is using 10GB of heap it is either working with a huge amount of data, or it's got memory leak issues (yes, they can happen in Java). It's probably nothing to do with the warnings though.

Answer (score 0):

3000 warnings == incompetent programmers == poor code == poorly preforming code in space and time

the warnings are the least of your worries!

I would still strive to fix them, because you will have to review the code around them and will probably find many many many more serious issues, so it is not a fruitless exercise.